# How to create these background circles and wave patterns in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best approach to create these background circles,wave patterns & namasthe symbol?
[image]

Comment: Are you referring `faint circles` as the hole-circular shape? can you mark on image

Comment: create these kind of pictures on photoshop or illustrator or direct import it to assets and then call it through asset.image it will be good if u want to create then u have to use painter widget to achieve this but it will take more effort and time :-)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, the semi circles on the screen.

Comment: are those two(`hello` and `namaste` ) on same UI

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, these are initial welcome screens of an app.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying for widget called wave.

Code Snippet:

```
      Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  margin:
    EdgeInsets.all(
      50
    ),
  height: 120,
  width: 200,
  child:
  WaveWidget(
    config: CustomConfig(
      gradients: [
        [Colors.red, Color(0xEEF44336)],
        [Colors.redAccent, const Color(0x77E57373)],
        [Colors.orange, Color(0x66FF9800)],
        [Colors.yellow, Color(0x55FFEB3B)]
      ],
      durations: [35000, 19440, 10800, 6000],
      heightPercentages: [0.20, 0.23, 0.25, 0.30],
      blur: MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.solid, 1),
      gradientBegin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      gradientEnd: Alignment.topRight,
    ),

    waveAmplitude: 0,
    size: Size(
      100,
      100
    ),
  )
  ,
);
```

Read documentation for clear view:

https://pub.dev/packages/wave

Answer (score -2):

The best way to achieve that is to import those as images in a folder called /assets and use them by doing Image.asset